# How to convert time dependent values into rising, staying and falling?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array like this

```
time_in_seconds;value
2.353463;0
2.453463;10
2.553463;10
2.653463;9
2.853463;0
3.353463;0
5.353463;2
```

I would like to populate a `List<Times>` with

```
public class Times
{
  public double[] time_rising_start {get;set;}
  public double[] time_rising_end {get;set;}
  public double[] time_staying_end {get;set;}
  public double[] time_falling_end {get;set;}
}
```

where

```
double[] time = new double[2];
time[0] = time_start
time[1] = time_start_value
```

respectively

```
double[] time = new double[2];
time[0] = time_end
time[1] = time_end_value
```

There are many approaches, I am looking for an intelligent way to summarize this into rising, staying and falling. That means

```
2.353463;0
2.453463;10
```

is rising, 0 -> 10

```
2.453463;10
2.553463;10
```

is staying, 10 -> 10

```
2.553463;10
2.653463;9
2.853463;0
```

is falling, 10 -> 9 -> 0

```
2.853463;0
3.353463;0
```

is staying, 0 -> 0

etc.

`time_rising_start` and `time_falling_end` should always be at `value = 0`. In the mentioned example, it is

```
  time_rising_start = 2.353463;
  time_rising_end = 2.453463;
  time_staying_end = 2.553463;
  time_falling_end = 2.853463;
```

next object

```
  time_rising_start = 3.353463;
  ...
```

It should be able to handle slight changes like `value`

```
0
10
11
10
11
12
7
3
0
```

should amount to

```
0 <- time_rising_start
10 <- time_rising_end
11
10
11
12 <- time_staying_end
7
3
0 <- time_falling_end
```

Comparing to the previous value is easy. I would look if it was lower then it's rising etc.. But as this is not so simple I am looking for an efficient approach.

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are facing there? and what approach did you try so far?

Comment: @Thomas What do you not understand?

Comment: I think it would be good if oyu also separately state again what you are looking for (at the bottom of the question.  it is too easily overlooked otherwise. additionally it is not completely clear what you tried exactly so far

Comment: @Thomas By sharing what I did, I spoil the answers. Do you want me to spoil the answers and lead them into my direction of thinking that I want to get out of?

Comment: It looks like you need a simple state machine. Have you tried implementing one?

Comment: @vitalis belive me when I say the ppl here will also take other directions into consideration but they want to see what you tried so far. Else downvotes are coming the way almost surely as they get the impression you did try nothing at all and you want them to do your work instead of helping you achieving what you intend to do. Seen it quite a lot of times even where it was not the case. That is why I mention that it is always good to show what you tried so far.

Comment: @IanMercer I read the term `simple state machine` for the first time in my life.

Comment: @Thomas I designed `Times` and formulated the task itself, formatted it so others can easily comprehend it.

Answer (score 3):

Create a set of states (an enum for example): `Initial`, `Rising`, `Falling`, `Steady`.

Track the `state` and the last seen value `current` and `current_time`.

In pseudo code:

```
state = Initial 
current = first value
current_time = first time

foreach (value,time) after first
 switch on the state
  case Initial:
    if (value > current_value) { ... output rising, state = Rising }
    else ...
    current = value
  case Rising:
    if (value > current_value) { // do nothing, still rising }
    ...
```

As each value is processed the state machine needs to decide if a change of state is needed and whether to output something. In some states, some values will do nothing but advance to the next value. At the end you may need to output one more value.

This is a classic state machine implementation. There are more advanced state machines (hierarchical ones). Every developer should learn how a state machine works and how to implement one because they are quite common.

[UML State Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine) is a good reference on the topic.